# Verify Error in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm facing issue in my project while deploying it to GAE.The problem is unique for me. If  i try to add new java class to my project and if  i deploy it in GAE i'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from 
final class at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-60b3bee5bc3046
```

I'm not able to resolve this issue. If i remove the same class which i added, the application is working fine. I'm using `appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18`and java 7.

Comment: is the new class empty? if not, can you please provide the code?

Comment: if i add simple bean class also it is showing same error .

Comment: It's not an empty class, I added a pojo class and i got the same error. When i removed the class even the java.lang.VerifyError is resolved.